Let $A \in K^{n, n}$, $B \in K^{m,m}$ and $C \in K^{n,m}$ with $rank(C) = m$ and $AC = CB$. Every eigenvalue of B is also an eigenvalue of A.
Let K be a field, $n \ge m$ and $A \in K^{n, n}$, $B \in K^{m,m}$ and $C \in K^{n,m}$ with $rank(C) = m$ and $AC = CB$. Show, that every eigenvalue of B is also an eigenvalue of A.
My anwser so far:
Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $B$ concerning the eigenvector $z \in K^m$. Considering the vector $x = Cz \in K^m$.
Because $rank(C) = m$, $Cz \ne 0 \Leftrightarrow z \ne 0$.
Now we get
$$Bz = \lambda z \\ CBz = \lambda C z \\ \stackrel{AC = CB}{\Longleftrightarrow} ACz = \lambda Cz \\ Ax = \lambda x.$$
Therefore $\lambda$ ist also an eigenvalue of $A$ concerning $x = Cz \in K^n$.
My intuition: I assume, that $n = m$. But as $n$ can be larger than $m$, we need to expand $x$ somehow and argue with the rank, that this holds for every $\lambda$.
How could this be done?

Your argument works exactly the same if $n > m$.
To see this invoke the rank-nullity theorem, which states in your case:
$$\text{rank}(C)+\text{dim}(\text{ker}(C))=\text{dim}(K^m).$$
Because by assumption $\text{dim}(K^m)=\text{rank}(C)=m$ it follows that $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(C))=0$, i.e. $\text{ker}(C)=\\{0\\}$. This means $Cz=0\iff z=0$. So since your eigenvector $z\neq 0$, you also have
$Cz \neq 0$.
